# What audio live looper for Ubuntu?

Tags: 18.04, sound, music

I need a simple loop tool I can record a first loop that sets the length of the loop automatically and then the possibility to add more recordings on separate tracks in addition to this first track.

Is there a current and updated software for a **Live Looper for Ubuntu**?

I just found old products without updates and not working.
Thank you!

Comment: For Ubuntu 18.04 there is [Sooperlooper](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+package/sooperlooper), doesn't that work?

Comment: Thanks. It seems to be a nice one.
And by trying to install it I realized that my `jackd` doesn't work well.